# Using next_permutation to get all combinations of length N C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to do the classic ***all combinations of a list*** problem and I found this code here on the forum that works wonderful. However, I would like to limit the combinations to N elements. I know there are many similar threads but I am yet to find a ***simple*** solution to this issue. Are there any simple solutions to this that doesn't require adding a lot of new lines of code?

```
std::string next() {
    int n = 2; // Will only give me combinations of length 2
    std::vector<std::string> arr = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
    do {
        for(auto& i: arr)
            std::cout << i;
        std::cout << '\n';
    } while(std::next_permutation(arr.begin(), arr.end()));  
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. That's life. Sometimes we find a piece of code that almost does what we want. We need to understand how it works and adjust to our needs. It's cool to start that process on small method. Please search to understand what this code does. Then experiment with it by yourself. It's your opportunity to exercise your brain and this way to prepare it for bigger and bigger chalenges in future. I keep my fingers crossed for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple is to use only the first two elements of any permutation and skip duplicates. To have uniques you can use a `std::set`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>


void next() {
    int n = 2; // Will only give me combinations of length 2
    std::vector<std::string> arr = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end()); 
    
    std::set<std::vector<std::string>> result;
    
    do {
        result.emplace(arr.begin(),arr.begin()+n);
    } while(std::next_permutation(arr.begin(), arr.end()));  

    for (const auto& c : result) {
        for (const auto& e : c) std::cout << e ;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    next();
}
```

Output:

```
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bc
bd
be
ca
cb
cd
ce
da
db
dc
de
ea
eb
ec
ed
```

PS: Your function is declared to return a `std::string` but it does not return anything. This is undefined behavior. When I tried to run it I got a double free runtime error.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is because it will check for a match with a string and once it matches, it will return that combination.